# program outputing 1 more than actual number of elements in array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I wrote a program which takes words in each line and keeps it in the array then we have to print each element and the total number of the element. I am unable to find why every time it gives the count of element 1 more than the original value
program

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
declare -a arr
line="buffer"
while [ -n "$line" ]
do
    read line
    arr[$i]="$line"
    i=`expr $i + 1 `
done
for i in ${arr[@]}
do
    echo "element $i"
done
echo ${#arr[@]}
```

test case

```
Nauru
Nepal
Netherlands
NewZealand
Nicaragua
Niger
Nigeria
NorthKorea
Norway
```

output

```
element Nauru
element Nepal
element Netherlands
element NewZealand
element Nicaragua
element Niger
element Nigeria
element NorthKorea
element Norway
10
```

Expected output

```
element Nauru
element Nepal
element Netherlands
element NewZealand
element Nicaragua
element Niger
element Nigeria
element NorthKorea
element Norway
9
```

Comment: Try it with quotes: `for i in "${arr[@]}"; ...`

Comment: You should read up on `mapfile` for a better way to read a file into an array.

Answer (score 1):

What the other answers said.  It's a [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error).  Note that `bash` offers several shortcuts for jobs like this.  By using those shortcuts the whole program can be reduced to:

```
mapfile -t arr < data
printf 'element %s\n' "${arr[@]}"
echo "${#arr[@]}"
```

The advantage being fewer variables to confuse, `mapfile` does the initialization, and no loops.

Answer (score 0):

How do you exit the `while` loop? You do it by entering an empty string (simply by hitting `Return`). Well, the loop does not break instantly, **but puts the empty string in the next element of the array** and increments `i` value (that, bear in mind, is used for nothing).

So, all in all, the array length will always be one more than expected. If still not clear, consider this:

```
$ a=()
$ echo ${#a[@]}
0
$ a[0]=         #Assigns empty string
$ echo ${#a[@]}
1
```

Answer (score 0):

When `read line` produces an empty value of `line`, you still add it to the array *before* checking if you should exit the loop.

When you iterate over the array, the unquoted parameter expansion discards the empty final element; quoting it (`for i in "${arr[@]}"`) would produce

```
element Nauru
element Nepal
element Netherlands
element NewZealand
element Nicaragua
element Niger
element Nigeria
element NorthKorea
element Norway
element 
10
```

Check the value first, breaking if necessary, *then* update the array.

```
declare -a arr
while read line
do
    arr+=("$line")
done
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo "element $i"
done
echo "${#arr[@]}"
```

Comment: The usual idiom is `while read line ...`.  Using `do/break` is cumbersome.

Comment: <facepalm/> For some reason, I overlooked that while deleting the other code.